# Help comparing CreatedDate with a specific Date

Tags: apex, soql, class

can anybody help me with this query, i am trying to get records from 1/1/2014
i don't know how to do the right comparison. I will appreciate any help.

```
Date d = date.newInstance(2014, 1, 1);

 AggregateResult[] groupedPO2
 =  [SELECT Buyer_Lookup__c , count(id)
     FROM Purchase_Order__c 
     WHERE  Invoice_Verified__c = null AND PNO__c = null AND Status__c ='Placed' AND  (CreatedDate > d)
     GROUP BY Buyer_Lookup__c LIMIT 50000 ];


for(AggregateResult po2 : groupedPO2){
   po2Size= po2.get('expr0'); 
}
```

Comment: I also tried this DATEVALUE(Created date) > DATEVALUE('1/1/2014') no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague has worked out this solution where your term:

```
CreatedDate > d
```

should be replaced by:

```
DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) >= :d
```

(I'm not sure if you want records from that day and beyond, or from the day after and beyond or on that date; use >=, > or = respectively.)

Details in his blog [Gotcha: convertTimezone() must be used in SOQL Date functions dealing with Datetime](http://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/). And DAY_ONLY is documented in [Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm).

Comment: hello Keith, i need to get all the record from 1/1/2014 to today..

Comment: Then >= is the one.

Comment: thank you so much Keith, you are always helping me. I really appreciate it